# Twitter-like follow system with PHP

Tags: php

How can I make a Twitter-like follow system between users on the site?

I am just wondering what is the basic structure to make something like that.

Comment: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Add-Twitter-like-functions-to-any-application-using-PHP/42890

Comment: I would search the internet for a jQuery plugin to do that if I was up for the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database table with two columns: `follower` and `following`.

You can either have a third column for the primary key, or use a multi-column primary key. The latter would enforce uniqueness at the database level (since you can't follow the same person multiple times simultaneously).

Comment: Jordan, I haven't really tried anything yet, I'm just trying to see how the structure of the database and the structure is.